# Listener видимость переменных

Tags: laravel

Добрый день.

Отправляю Email через Mail фасад.

```
Mail::to(['test@gmail.com'], 'Джон Смит')
            ->queue(new TestMail($test = 'тест'));
```

Class письма:

```
class TestMail extends Mailable{

    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $test;

    public function __construct($test){
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function build(){
        return $this->view('emails.welcome')->subject('Ваш заказ успешно принят')
            ->with(['tests'=>$this->test]);
    }
}
```

Есть штатное событие [MessageSent](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Mail/Events/MessageSent.html)

я его регистрирую в EventServiceProvider:

```
 protected $listen = [
        'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
            'App\Listeners\LogSentMessage',
        ]
    ];
```

Lisntener:

```
class LogSentMessage{

    public function __construct(){}
     
    public function handle(MessageSent $event){
        var_dump($event->message);
        var_dump($event->test);
        var_dump($event->tests);
    }
}
```

Хочу сделать логирование писем. Для этого нужно тело сообщения и доп инфа которая будет передаваться в переменную.

Подскажите как получить переменную test в Listener?

Comment: В message все у тебя должно быть, вопрос как ты все это пытаешься перехватить , проверь лучше не `var_dump` а `dd($event->message)` а еще лучше сразу в лог `\Log::alert('Перехват сообщения', ['message'=>$event->message])`

Comment: $event->message  Отлично перехватывается. Мне надо перехватить test

Comment: так тогда свое сообщение отправки создавай и в конструкторе Event делай переменную, ты ж [смотри](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Mail/Events/MessageSent.php) у них там ток message